# Heroku - failure in opening

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I am a complete newbie to Heroku and have been following their instructions for getting started with Node.js on Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs).  I have been successful up until the point when I use `heroku open`.  At that point I receive the following error:

```
Opening my-app-name... Failure in opening http://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/ with  
options {}: Unable to find a browser command. If this is unexpected, Please rerun with 
environment variable LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true or the '-d' commandline option and file a bug at
https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/new
```

I have set the LAUNCHY_DEBUG environment variable to true and have verified that it set properly by using the command `heroku config:get LAUNCHY_DEBUG`.  But when I try the command `heroku open`, it still gives me the exact same error.  I was expect to at least see details?  I also tried running it using the -d command line option per the second recommendation, but it states `Invalid argument: "-d"`.

I have a full working app that will run on my local machine.  However, when I use `foreman start` from the heroku toolbelt and navigate to localhost:5000 it does not connect.  It does state that it's running on the console:

```
21:44:51 web.1  | started with pid 1457
21:44:53 web.1  | Express server listening on port 5000
```

I'm assuming that these two issues may be connected.

My searches have resulted in nothing regarding this error, so I don't know how to proceed.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that it (launchy) cannot find and open your browser; please check the configuration of your machine (default browser, etc.).

You can just launch your browser manually and go to `http://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: Thank you, I understand the launchy error now. Unfortunately for me, launching it manually doesn't work either; it gives me an application error.  As it turns out, my web dyno crashes immediately. Looks like I have a completely separate problem to work through. Thanks again!